# How to avoid duplicating code for accessing properties WITHOUT using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have these structure

```
class A : IFoo {
   Foo(){
      //do something
   }
   IList<B> Bs {get;set;}
   IList<C> Cs {get;set;}
}

class B : IFoo {
   Foo(){
      //do something
   }
   IList<D> Ds {get;set;}
}

class C : IFoo {
   Foo(){
      //do something
   }
}

class D : IFoo {
   Foo(){
      //do something
   }
}

class Helper{
  Bar(A a){
     a.Foo();
     Bar(a.Bs);
     Bar(a.Cs);
  }

  Bar(IList<B> bs)
  {
     foreach(var b in bs)
     {
        Bar(b);
     }
  }

  Bar(B b)
  {
     b.Foo();
     Bar(b.Ds);
  }

  Bar(IList<C> cs)
  {
     foreach(var c in cs)
     {
        Bar(c);
     }
  }

  Bar(C c)
  {
     c.Foo();
  }

  Bar(IList<D> ds)
  {
     foreach(var d in ds)
     {
        Bar(d);
     }
  }

  Bar(D d)
  {
     d.Foo();
  }
}
interface IFoo {
  void Foo();
}
```

As you see a lot of code is repeated in `Helper` class (i.e. method `Bar`) for different types of `A,B,C,IList<A>,IList<B>,IList<C>`. Also when a new list property is added to the classes I need to get back and change the Helper class which is somehow in contradiction with Open/Close principal.

I know how to use `Reflection` to solve the issue, but I was searching for another smart and neat way to solve this issue and not using Reflection.

I am free to add new `Interface`s but not base class

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: That looks complicated? what are you trying to achieve? May be use `dynamic` or `expando object`  if you do not want `Reflection`

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown Even with dynamic the issue still exists, I need to keep all the Helper class structure and copy paste the code when a new class is added

Comment: Does method `Foo()` exist on the `IFoo` interface?

Comment: @StuartLC Yes, it is

Comment: How about using code generation? For generating the code you'll need reflection, but once it has been generated you won't. The code can be generated in a prebuild task or even sooner by using an IDE plugin.

Comment: @EvilTak Yes, that would be an option, before going to that direction I wanted to see if there is better way

Comment: There is a way using `Expressions`, but it requires some reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that method `Foo()` exists on the IFoo interface, and given that your `Bar` methods for B, C and D do nothing other than invoke the `Foo` implementation for the class, why not remove the `Bar` overloads altogether (since the dependency coupling is only to the interface method `Foo()`)

Your looped method becomes (renamed from `Bar(IList<B/C/D> bs)`):

```
void InvokeFoo(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
{
   foreach(var foo in foos)
   {
      foo.Foo();
   }
}
```

Which would be invoked:

```
Bar(A a){
   a.Foo();
   InvokeFoo(a.Bs);
   InvokeFoo(a.Cs);
}
```

**Edit**

The above answer misses the fact that classes (e.g. B) can have child collections, through which you also need to iterate. If these child collections are arbitrary in number (e.g. A has 2 such collections, B has 1, and C and D none), and given your statement that you can't modify the actual classes `A`, `B`, `C` etc, you could specify a 'special' action to be taken for each class. This would be a naive implementation, which only will work for one level of recursion (which is what you have):

```
class Helper
{
    public void Bar(A a)
    {
        a.Foo();
        InvokeFoo(a.Bs, foo => InvokeFoo(((B)foo).Ds));
        InvokeFoo(a.Cs);
    }

    void InvokeFoo(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos, Action<IFoo> childAction = null)
    {
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            foo.Foo();
            childAction?.Invoke(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

**Making this more generic / Recursive**

Since it seems you aren't allowed to modify the classes (only the helper), violation of the Open+Closed principal of SOLID seems inevitable (since the navigation is done by an external observer).

As a poor man's form of polymorphicism, and to keep the 'smell' in one place, what you could do is provide an overload to assist each type walk it's children. The default behaviour (as per my first code) is simply to invoke `Foo`, if no type is found:

```
class Helper
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, Action<IFoo>> SpecialClassActions 
        = new Dictionary<Type, Action<IFoo>>
        {
            // Provide special handling for walking classes which have children
            {
                typeof(A),
                foo =>
                {
                    InvokeChildFoo(((A)foo).Bs);
                    InvokeChildFoo(((A)foo).Cs);
                }
            },
            {
                typeof(B),
                foo =>
                {
                    InvokeChildFoo(((B)foo).Ds);
                }
            }
            // Add more handling here as new subtypes are added
        };

    static void WalkFooHierarchy(IFoo foo)
    {
        foo.Foo();

        Action<IFoo> specialChildAction;
        if (SpecialClassActions.TryGetValue(foo.GetType(), out specialAction))
        {
            specialChildAction(foo);
        }
    }

    //  Replaces your Bar(IList<> ..) methods
    static void InvokeChildFoo(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
    {
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            WalkFooHierarchy(foo);
        }
    }
```

You then kick the process off by starting to walk from your root level object:

```
public void Bar(A a)
{
    Helper.WalkFooHierarchy(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Then how Foo is called on D?(which is a property on B)

Comment: Yeah - I missed that B recursed on its children D's. Will rethink + update.

Comment: BTW your solution will reduce Bar overloads for lists ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the OPEN/CLOSE principle intact, you can go with something like this -

- Each class will extend as necessary.
- New class does not need to modify old class- `Helper`. So the implementation becomes somewhat like the one below. NO matter how many class you add, each class is responsible for there own `Foo` and `Bar` implementation.

Example -

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
}

public abstract class BaseFoo : IFoo
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    public virtual void Bar()
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}

public class A : BaseFoo //replace with IFoo if you do not want the base class, in that case implement both methods
{
    IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
    IList<C> Cs { get; set; }

    public override void Bar()
    {
        base.Bar();

        foreach (var b in Bs)
        {
            b.Bar();
        }

        foreach (var c in Cs)
        {
            c.Bar();
        }
    }
}

public class B : BaseFoo //replace with IFoo if you do not want the base class, in that case implement both methods
{
    IList<D> Ds { get; set; }

    public override void Bar()
    {
        base.Bar();

        foreach (var d in Ds)
        {
            d.Bar();
        }
    }
}

public class C : BaseFoo //replace with IFoo if you do not want the base class, in that case implement both methods
{

}

public class D : BaseFoo //replace with IFoo if you do not want the base class, in that case implement both methods
{

}

public static class Helper
{
    public static void Bar(params IFoo[] foos)
    {
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            foo.Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on priceless suggestions and solutions I ended up like below, this solution is Open/Closed and by adding another list only that class should be changed and all of the overloads of `Bar` in `Helper` class is removed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Helper.Bar(new A());
    }
}

public class A : IFoo, IMap
{
    public A()
    {
        Cs = new List<C> { new C(), new C() };
        Bs = new List<B> { new B(), new B() };
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public List<C> Cs { get; set; }

    public List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> Map()
    {
        return this.CreateMap()
            .Then(x => ((List<B>)x.Bs).ToList<IFoo>())
            .Then(x => ((List<C>)x.Cs).ToList<IFoo>());
    }

}

public class B : IFoo, IMap
{
    public B()
    {
        Ds = new List<D> { new D(), new D() };
    }
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    public List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> Map()
    {
        return this.CreateMap()
            .Then(x => ((List<D>)x.Ds).ToList<IFoo>());
    }

    public List<D> Ds { get; set; }
}

public class C : IFoo, IMap
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }

    public List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> Map()
    {
        return this.CreateMap();
    }
}

public class D : IFoo, IMap
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D");
    }

    public List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> Map()
    {
        return this.CreateMap();
    }
}

public static class Mapper
{
    public static List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> CreateMap(this IFoo item)
    {
        return new List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>>();
    }

    public static List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> Then(this List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> list, Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>> expression)
    {
        list.Add(expression);
        return list;
    }
}
public class Helper
{
    public static void Bar(dynamic obj)
    {
        obj.Foo();
        var map = obj.Map();
        if (map != null)
        {
            foreach(var item in map)
            {
                var lists = item(obj);
                foreach(var list in lists)
                {
                    Bar(list);
                }
            }
        }
    } 

}

public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

public interface IMap 
{
    List<Func<dynamic, List<IFoo>>> Map();
}
```

@brainlesscoder, @StuartLC : since your solutions are also correct I only up-vote them and I don't tag any of the solutions as answer to keep this thread open and might someone else suggests a better solution than us. If you think my solution is also good please up-vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be the most straight-forward way to do this:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void Bar<F>(F f) where F : IFoo
    {
        f.Foo();
        Helper.Bar((f as A)?.Bs);
        Helper.Bar((f as A)?.Cs);
        Helper.Bar((f as B)?.Ds);
    }

    public static void Bar<F>(IList<F> fs) where F : IFoo
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            foreach (var f in fs)
            {
                Helper.Bar(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if the rest of the code is defined like this:

```
public class A : IFoo
{
    public void Foo() { Console.Write("A"); }
    public IList<B> Bs { get; set; } = new List<B>() { new B(), new B(), };
    public IList<C> Cs { get; set; } = new List<C>() { new C(), new C(), };
}

public class B : IFoo
{
    public void Foo() { Console.Write("B"); }
    public IList<D> Ds { get; set; } = new List<D>() { new D(), new D(), };
}

public class C : IFoo
{
    public void Foo() { Console.Write("C"); }
}

public class D : IFoo
{
    public void Foo() { Console.Write("D"); }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}
```

...then you can run this:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var c = new C();
var d = new D();

Helper.Bar(a);
Helper.Bar(b);
Helper.Bar(c);
Helper.Bar(d);
```

...and you get `ABDDBDDCCBDDCD` as expected as the output.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, the result is as expected, the only issue is when a collection is added to a class Bar needs to be changed to and is in contradict with OC

Comment: @RezaRahmati - Can you explain "when a collection is added to a class Bar needs to be changed to and is in contradict with OC"? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean for example if a new List property is added to class D, not only class D needs to be changed but also Helper class, and this is not obeying Open/Closed principal

Comment: @RezaRahmati - Which is no different to how the OP's class would have worked. At least with my approach you could wire up a dynamic approach to allow it to cope with future types. It'd just need a `Dictionary<Type, delegate>` to do that.